# How to ensure that last page is always opened?

Tags: support

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/apache-spark?page=101&tab=noanswers

The last page could change, e.g. 102, 101. How to ensure that the last page is always opened?

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: I would like to see the lowest voted unanswered spark questions when I open a web browser

Comment: TO GIVE MOAR DOWNVOTES!

Comment: @CodyGray That is an assumption. I want to answer the questions

Comment: Why do you _want_ to answer _downvoted_ questions? That sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: @Cerbrus Maybe to try having the [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge (GL&HF). ;p

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in functionality to do that.

I have created this userscript that achieves what you want by navigating (and then bookmark it for example) to the page -1.

Here is the script that happily runs with GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        go to last page
// @namespace   https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @include     *//stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/*?page=-1&tab=noanswers
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

/*global $, console */

(function () {
    'use strict';
    // no regex, no glory
    var regex = /.*\/unanswered\/tagged\/((.*)\?).*/g,
        matches;

    // find the tagname
    if (((matches = regex.exec(document.location.toString())) !== null) && (matches.length === 3)) {
        // fetch first page
        $.get('/unanswered/tagged/' + matches[2] + '?page=1&pagesize=50&tab=noanswers', function (data) {
            var prev, last;
            // find the last page in the pager
            $(data).find('div.pager > a').each(function () {
                prev = last;
                last = this;
            });
            // I assumed here that there are always more than 
            // 3 pages in the pager
            if (prev) {
                // navigate to the last page
                document.location = prev.href;
            }
        });
    }
}());
```

After you installed it, the script does its job if you visit:

> [`https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/haskell?page=-1&tab=noanswers`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/haskell?page=-1&tab=noanswers)

notice the `page=-1`. Without the userscript you'll get an empty page. But as the userscript is only configured to run on this page it will starts its parsing and redirecting but won't interfere with other pages.