# How do you search questions by tag then sort by oldest?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

You can search questions by tag and sort by newest with `sort=newest`. For example, you can search for [*Unity*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d?sort=newest&pageSize=50) questions and sort by newest, but you can't search question by [oldest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d?sort=oldest&pageSize=50) by doing `sort=oldest`.

Why is this feature not present? Maybe it is available, but I am missing it?

Comment: Sort by newest, and go to the last page of questions?

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340145/4751173)

Comment: @CodyGray Didn't think about that. Although, that means you will be navigating backwards....

Comment: @Glorfindel Not really.  I do not want to ensure that last page is always opened. Simply want to search and sort by oldest....